# ffmpeg filter_complex loop doesn't start from beginning

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to overlay a sequence of images over an input video and loop over the sequence until input video is finished.

The input video duration is 00:04:09.71 at 25fps, and image sequence contains 497 png files.

**The problem is that overlay loop (image sequence) starts at about frame #400 after one iteration but it should start at frame #0.**

Here is the command:

`ffmpeg  -i hq26368874313361335.mp4 -i "Seq\seq_%5d.png" -filter_complex "[1:v]loop=-1:size=497[top];[0:v][top]overlay=shortest=1"  temp.ts`

and here is the ffmpeg output:

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libmfx
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'hq26368874313361335.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.82.100
  Duration: 00:04:09.71, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 588 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 502 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 79 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : TimeCodeHandler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
Input #1, image2, from 'Seq\seq_%5d.png':
  Duration: 00:00:19.88, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
File 'temp.ts' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> overlay:main (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (png) -> loop (graph 0)
  overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (mpeg2video)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> mp2 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mpegts, to 'temp.ts':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 90k tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 mpeg2video
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 384 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 mp2
[swscaler @ 0000027d8520e6e0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
frame= 6242 fps=101 q=31.0 Lsize=   32413kB time=00:04:09.69 bitrate=1063.4kbits/s speed=4.02x
video:17134kB audio:11700kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 12.413462%
```

Edit:
[this](https://takhtesefid.org/video_full_2/hq26368874313361335.mp4) is the input video and [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nyw7iqp14e5azy4/seq.zip?dl=0) is the sequence of png files.

Comment: Do you get the same issue with demuxer looping? --> `-loop 1 -i "Seq\seq_%5d.png"` (remove the loop filter).

Comment: @Mulvya, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @AshkanNourzadeh I'm unable to duplicate the issue using the loop filter. Please provide the inputs if they are required to duplicate this issue.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard, added link to inputs in the question.

Comment: Quick look with `ffprobe -show_frames -select_streams v` indicates that the pixel format of `hq26368874313361335.mp4` changes from yuv420p to yuvj420p at 16.322031 which I'm guessing is the point at which it glitches. Probably due to concatenation of sources with varying parameters. Ran out of time to actually try anything but will try to look tomorrow. So not an issue with loop filter itself.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard, Thanks, good. Tried to fix the pixel format, problem disappeared. but why that affects the loop?

Comment: @AshkanNourzadeh I don't know why it behaves like that. Could be a bug or a regression, but I didn't look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ffprobe -show_frames -select_streams v hq26368874313361335.mp4` indicates that the pixel format of the input changes from yuv420p to yuvj420p at 16.322031 which is likely the point at which it glitches. Probably due to using the concat demuxer with inputs that vary parameters.

One solution is to make sure all inputs have the same pixel format before concatenation such as by using the format filter (`-vf format=yuv420p`) or `-pix_fmt yuv420p`.